# How to make the clickable buttons for start and stop for particular buttons from the loop of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have created the clickable buttons dynamically from the data(i.e based on the backend da ta number of buttons will come).

But the problem is while clicking on any button from start to stop, all the remaining buttons also changed to stop.

**.component.ts**

```
public isCollapsed = false;

toggleCollapse() {
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed
}
```

**.component.html**

```
  <ul class="list-group" >
                <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let y of data">

                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <h5>{{y.d1}}</h5>
                                <h6>Latitude: {{y.d2}}</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-text "> Longitude: {{y.d3}}</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3">

                               <button type="button" [ngClass]="isCollapsed ? 'btn btn-success btn-sm' : 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'" (click)="toggleCollapse()">
                         <span *ngIf="isCollapsed"> START </span>
                         <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed"> STOP</span>
                     </button>

                  

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Looks to me like isCollapsed is a component property. So if you use *ngIf="isCollapsed" or *ngIf="!isCollapsed" on all buttons that are generated, it will evaluate the same for all of them. You will need a unique condition for every button. Could you share a bit more code, so we can see how the buttons are generated?

Comment: @Leonardum, I have shared the more code ,above please help me how to toggle the present buttons only from start to stop.